# Connect and search the database then display that to a webpage?

Tags: php, sql-server

I have some code that connects to a localhost MySQL server and displays if that database contains any matches of the search box. But I am now trying to connect to a SQL Server database and I just can't get it to work. Am I doing something wrong?

```
try {
    $pdo = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=xxx.xx.xx.xx,1433;Database=Live", $username, $password);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    // $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    echo "Connected successfully";
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("
    SELECT * 
    FROM `dbo.Home` 
    WHERE `item_number` LIKE ? OR `stock_available` LIKE ?
");
$stmt->execute(["%" . $_POST['search'] . "%", "%" . $_POST['search'] . "%"]);       <---LINE 54
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();
if (isset($_POST['ajax'])) { echo json_encode($results); }
```

I get the following error:

> Connected successfully Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException:
> SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL
> Server]Incorrect syntax near 'dbo.Home'. in
> /usr/local/var/www/2-search.php:54 Stack trace: #0
> /usr/local/var/www/2-search.php(54): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1
> /usr/local/var/www/1-form.php(14): require('/usr/local/var/...') #2
> {main} thrown in /usr/local/var/www/2-search.php on line 54

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Back ticks (`\``) aren't a SQL Server delimit identifier, it's a MySQL delimit identifier. T-SQL uses Brackets (`[]`) and the ISO standard double quotes (`"`).

Comment: Use correct T-SQL syntax - `"SELECT * FROM dbo.[Home] WHERE [item_number] LIKE ? OR [stock_availabl] LIKE ?"`

Comment: Different databases have different syntax. Check that you have a basic understanding of SQL Server's syntax.

Comment: I thought this might be the case but I couldn't find the correct syntax

Comment: There are literally 1000s of SQL Server examples and tutorials available online, plus questions on here and other similar sites, and also the official documentation - which documents the key syntax concepts and, again, contains examples. To be honest it's a bit difficult to understand how you didn't managed to find any examples of basic query syntax...

Comment: I guess I wasn't looking for the correct thing my apologies, now I know i'll read up on the SQL Server syntax. I also have it working now. Many thanks